# Inserting text into pygame upon key input

Tags: python

When I run the program everything works except when I press the s key the text is not printed to the screen, here is the part of my code which is not working:

```
            elif event.key == K_s:
                fontObj = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
                textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render("Roar!!!", True, WHITE)
                textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()
                textRectObj.center = (200,100)
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurfaceObj,textRectObj)

            DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(LionCubImg,(LionCubX,LionCubY))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is the `elif` block triggered at all? SImpliest way of checking it is to put `print "key pressed!"` into it.

Comment: Did you import `K_s` from the module `pygame`? Try `pygame.K_s` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filling the Surface with green *after* you just printed some text to it, thus covering up the text you just added to the Surface.

Order matters when drawing on Surfaces in Pygame.

Comment: I would have simply added this as a comment, but I don't have the requisite rep. My apologies.